# CFA model interpretation

Tags: interpretation, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I received the following CFA model output. I wonder if anyone can help me understand how to interpret values on each path. For example, in factor 3, what does 1, 0.535, and p-value mean? I know that in factor 3, sleep get 1 because I put sleep in front of comm_level when I propose the model. I guess that means the parameters meaning can only be interpreted locally within each factor. Could anyone help with further interpretation? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not too familiar with identification processes. Based on the link, there are two types of identifications: the structural and the measurement models. Is "the structural" the theory of the model? Were you referring to the identification of "measurement models" in your comments? If yes, are there any measurements for that? If I misundertood, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "you received". Was that the model that you fit?

Are there no factor covariances?

0.535 is the loading for factor3 on commute_level. It's not very interesting, because it's (probably) the covariance / correlation between commute_level and sleep. You knew that before you fit the model, so the model doesnt't appear to be telling you anything you didn't already know.

The loading for sleep is 1.00 because if it wasn't, the model would not be identified.

Comment: By saying "I received" I meant that the figure above was the output coming out of my CFA analysis. I proposed the model, but then it is the analyses that gave me all the parameter values. I thought the values in the figure are estimates.

Comment: I didn’t realize covariance matrix could help with interpreting the estimates and p-values in the figure. I thought the covariance matrix was the relationship between factors, and the values in the figure only pointed to the relationship between indicators within each factor, but please let me know if I understood it wrong. I added the covariance matrix above if that helps with interpreting the figure.

Comment: What do you mean by “0.535 is the loading for factor3 on commute_level”? Is there a mathematical equation that could represent the relationship between these indicators and factors utilizing the given values? When you say “You knew that before you fit the model
”, what were you assuming that I knew: that there was correlation between commute level and factor 3 or the correlation/covariance between factor 3 and commute level is 0.535? I’m just confused. What does the model and the parameters tell me then?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: commute_level = 0.535 * factor1 + error
sleep = 1 * factor1 (+error, I think)

Comment: Your model doesn't tell you anything you could have known before you fit the model. It tells you nothing new. I say "The mean of this variable is 4" and I give you the data, and you run some complex models and say "The mean is 4". CFA is (as you've realized)  quite difficult to learn - it requires a different way of thinking about statistical models.

Comment: Thanks for listing the equation. I guess by saying "factor1" you actually mean "factor3".

Comment: I thought of CFA as something kind of like hypothesis testing. I first propose a structure: In your example, "the mean is 4" is the proposed hypothesis. The model output says "the mean is 4" supports the hypothesis. Although the only difference in CFA is that the output support is relative support as only tells whether one model structure is relatively a better fit than the other. Am I understanding you in the right direction?

Comment: Here comes another question. What would happen if the p-value is not significant? How to interpret the output figure in that case?

Comment: You might want to start a new question. It's not clear what your model actually looks like.

Comment: It's just a follow-up question. Because you said the parameters do not tell anything new. I just wonder if whether the p-value is significant or not also doesn't matter. There is no other model. I'm still trying to understand the meaning of the parameters.

Comment: It's not really possible to say with that model, without more details.

Comment: OK. Thank you! I might start a new question on this then.